# How can I extract data from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, scope, extract, text-extraction, observablehq

I am modifying an algorithm I found on observablehq.com. My goal is to extract data that is being messaged from a worker and save it to a text/csv file. I'm trying to save the arrays "points" and "weights", but I don't know where to start.

```js
sobelDotsWorker = {
  if (renderSobel){
    const context = sobelDotsContext;
    const worker = new Worker(sobeldotsScript);
    mutable sobelDotsRenders = 0;
    function messaged({data: {points, weights}}) {
      context.fillStyle = "#000";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
      context.beginPath();
      for (let i = 0, n = points.length; i < n; i += 2) {
        const w = Math.max(0.5, Math.sqrt(weights[i>>1])*0.5);
        if (w > 0.25) {
          const x = points[i];
          const y = points[i + 1];
          context.moveTo(x + w, y + w);
          context.arc(x, y, w, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        }
      }
      context.fill();
      mutable sobelDotsRenders += 1;
    }

    invalidation.then(() => worker.terminate());
    worker.addEventListener("message", messaged);
    worker.postMessage({data: imageGray.dark, sobelData: imageSobel.sobel, width, height, n, iterations});
    yield worker;
  }
}
```

Here is the original code.

Comment: `mutable sobelDotsRenders = 0;` this doesn't look like js

Comment: This is definitely JS but is there more to this code? There must be a Worker Class or constructor?

Comment: @Ryan are you running it inside an Observable notebook? could you share the link? but you probably want to push `points` and `weights` to an external variable outside the worker context , every new `messaged` call the worker is returning new data points.

Comment: @calmar Yes, it's an observable notebook. Here is the link: https://observablehq.com/d/08d36136f92e4cf6

Comment: @calmar It's a bit of a mess right now. I don't know any javascript, so I'm guessing and testing with pieces from other notebooks. What you say makes sense. I'll try to work in that direction.